# On SublimeText: How to revert changes on a closed file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I was implementing a task with Gulp and by mistake I did something wrong and all of my files now look like this

[image]

I was trying to use http://jsbeautifier.org/ but as I am using Angularjs, some variables/dependencies are imposible to recover, so right now I am struggling in order to see how I can revert the changes I did.

In the files I had open when I did that stupid change, all I did was `cmd+z` and everything went back to the normal state, but, what can I do with the files I had closed? Is imposible to do `cmd+z`. And also, I haven't commit anything so I can't just go back to the last commit or revert it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Much needed thing. I also want this.